# Connecting Custom layout class to collection view in code

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

**i have a small question about a custom layout class and i need to connect it to my collection view in code not by the story board because i create the whole project by code . any help, please ?**

**my main class**

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
class UserProfileController: UICollectionViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        collectionView?.backgroundColor = .white
        //fetchUser()
        collectionView?.dataSource = self
        collectionView?.delegate = self
        collectionView?.register(TestCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: mainCellId)    
    }


    fileprivate let mainCellId = "mainCellId"
    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: mainCellId, for: indexPath) as! TestCell

        return cell
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 15
    }
    override func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
}
```

**the custom layout class which need to connect it to the collection view in code not story board**

```
import UIKit

struct UltraVisualLayoutConstants {
    struct Cell {
        static let standardHeight: CGFloat = 100
        static let featuredHeight: CGFloat = 280
//        static let standardWidth: CGFloat = 100
//        static let featuredWidth: CGFloat = 280
    }
}

class UltraVisualLayout: UICollectionViewLayout {
    //  amount which users need to scroll before featured cell changes\
    let dragOffset: CGFloat = 180.0
    var cache = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]()
    //return item index of current featured cell
    var featuredItemIndex: Int {
        get {
            //use max to ensure that featureditemindex never be < 0
            return max(0 , Int(collectionView!.contentOffset.y / dragOffset))
        }
    }

    // returns value between 0 and 1 to represent how close the next cell becomes the featured cell
    var nextItemPercentegeOffset: CGFloat {
        get {
            return (collectionView!.contentOffset.y / dragOffset) - CGFloat(featuredItemIndex)
        }
    }    
    // return the width of collection view
    var width: CGFloat {
        get {

            guard let width = collectionView?.bounds.width else {return 0}
            return width
        }
    }
    // return the height of collection view
    var height: CGFloat {
        get {
            guard let height = collectionView?.bounds.height else {return 0}
            return height
        }
    }
    //returns the number of items in the collection view
    var numberOfItems: Int {
        get {
            return collectionView!.numberOfItems(inSection: 0)
        }
    }

    // MARK: UICollectionViewLayout
    // return the size of all content in collection view
     override var collectionViewContentSize: CGSize {
   let contentHeight = (CGFloat(numberOfItems) * dragOffset) + (height - dragOffset)
    return CGSize(width: width, height: contentHeight)
}
    override func prepare() {
        cache.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)

        let standardHeight = UltraVisualLayoutConstants.Cell.standardHeight
        let featuredHeight = UltraVisualLayoutConstants.Cell.featuredHeight
        var frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0)
        var y: CGFloat = 0
        for item in 0..<numberOfItems {
            let indexPath = NSIndexPath(item: item, section: 0)
            let attributes = UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes(forCellWith: indexPath as IndexPath)
            attributes.zIndex = item
            var height = standardHeight
            if indexPath.item == featuredItemIndex {
                let yOffset = standardHeight * nextItemPercentegeOffset
                y = collectionView!.contentOffset.y - yOffset
                height = featuredHeight
            } else if indexPath.item == (featuredItemIndex + 1) && indexPath.item != numberOfItems {
                let maxY = y + standardHeight
                height = standardHeight + max((featuredHeight - standardHeight) * nextItemPercentegeOffset, 0)
                y = maxY - height
            }
         frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: y, width: width, height: height)
            attributes.frame = frame
            cache.append(attributes)
            y = frame.maxY
        }

    }

    // return all attributes in cache whose frame intersects with the rect passed to the method
    override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {
        var layoutAttributes = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]()
        for attributes in cache {
            if attributes.frame.intersects(rect) {
                layoutAttributes.append(attributes)
            }
        }
        return layoutAttributes
    }

    // return true so that layout is continuously invalidated as the user scrolls
    override func shouldInvalidateLayout(forBoundsChange newBounds: CGRect) -> Bool {
        return true 
    }
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stackoverflow. Could you kindly post your code as text rather than an image so it is easier to read.

Comment: sry for that , i edited it @Chris Edgington

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **cannot** set the layout **programmatically** if you don't have an **initializer**. From the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionview/1618053-init):

> *layout*
>
> The layout object to use for organizing items. The collection
> view stores a strong reference to the specified object. **Must not be
> nil**.

Since you seem to be using the **storyboard**, you'll have to set it there.

[image]

Once you create you layout class in code, it will show up when you click you collection view on the storyboard. The **default** layout will be set to **Flow**, when you change it to **Custom**, a new class field will show up. When you click that, it will list your layout class. You can choose it and set it from there.

However if you are initializing your storyboard programmatically, then you just need to pass it as a parameter to your initializer.

```
var collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: yourFrame, collectionViewLayout: customCollectionViewLayout)    // pass your custom collection view instance
```

Comment: thanks for replying . how can i use the initializer in the right way ? that is what i want . i know the way to connect it in story board but i can't connect it in code in the main class if that possible . i don't use story board

Comment: @AhmedSeddek if you don't use storyboard, why is your `collectionView` an optional?

Comment: i don't know , when i create  it , xcode put optional front of it after adding delegate or data source or register the cell . am trying new animation through custom layout and i found the custom layout class in tutorial but it uses the same way u said by connecting it through story board not code :/

Comment: @AhmedSeddek please show the code (edit it to the question) where you initialize the UICollectionView.

Comment: this is the full code of my code and this is my TestCell class                            import UIKit

class TestCell: BaseCell {
    override func setupUI() {
        backgroundColor = .purple
    }
}

Comment: @AhmedSeddek UI elements are rarely declared as optionals in code. Most of the time, they are initialized lazily. But if you use a storyboard, then it might be an optional. That is why i'm asking you to show the code where you initialize it. Like `var collectionView = UICollectionView...`

Comment: @AhmedSeddek If this is your full code, then it is probably on a storyboard. Unless you find the initialization on code, you can't set the custom layout to it. It is a parameter in the initializer.

Comment: ok , could u please try it in xcode now ? just copy paste the code :D am waiting for any suggestion and thanks for trying to help

Comment: @AhmedSeddek I don't need to try it on xcode to tell that it won't work, because there is no initializer for you collectionview which mean either you use a storyboard or you have done it somewhere else. You can maybe share your project and then maybe i'd be able to tell from that.

Comment: 'class MainTabBarController: UITabBarController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        let userProfileController = UserProfileController(collectionViewLayout: layout)
        userProfileController.tabBarItem.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "profile_unselected")
        userProfileController.tabBarItem.selectedImage = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "profile_selected")
        tabBar.tintColor = .black
        viewControllers = [userProfileController, UIViewController()]
    }
}'

Comment: the problem was in this layout i forgot tht i defined it

Comment: so i changed it to the custom one and it worked , thanks for helping with your comments